# How to calculate the difference between two dates in hours with java?

Tags: java, time, java-time, timedelta, localtime

I have to calculate the **difference** bettween two **dates** where is one from the user`s input and the other is the current time. Here is what I have so far:

```
long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.print("Enter Time-in(hh:mm)");
String start = input.next();
String newTime[] = start.split(":");
String h = newTime[0];
String m = newTime[1];
String s = newTime[2];

int newH = Integer.parseInt(h);
int newM = Integer.parseInt(m);

LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.now();
long hr=ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(time1,time2);
System.out.println("Total number of hours: " + hr);
```

Comment: Start by creating a new `LocalTime` (or `LocalDateTime`) from the time values the user enters

Comment: `LocalTime().of(newH, newM)` for example, then you have something to which you can compare to

Comment: Can you please remove the `javascript` tag?

Comment: `LocalTime.of(newH, newM)` or `LocalTime.parse(start)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer im sorry im not sure what to compare it with what....

Comment: @shmosel (like this?)
                  LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.now(); 
                  LocalTime.parse(start);
                  long hr=ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(time1,time2);
                  System.out.println("Total number of hours: "+hr);

Comment: You forgot about `time2`.

Comment: `long hr=ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(LocalTime().of(newH, newM),LocalTime.now());` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: A tip for your next questions on Stack Overflow, it’s easier to help you if you explain clearly and precisely how your code fails to solve your problem; that is, the difference between desired behaviour and your program’s observed behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

```
    System.out.print("Enter Time-in(hh:mm)");
    String start=input.next(); //make sure it have "hh:mm" format
    LocalTime userTime = LocalTime.parse(start);
    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();


    long diff = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(currentTime, userTime);
```

Comment: Should solve OPs question, good! However you could improve the quality of your answer by also explaining what the code does. For example how `LocalTime` works and which pattern it expects at `LocalTime#parse`. It would also be helpful to provide a link from the Java-API like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: i tried the code but after entering the time in (hh:mm) it shows error....

Comment: so when entering the number do we have to split??

Comment: System.out.print("Enter Time-in hh:mm");
                   String start=input.next();
                                        
                  
                 
                  
                  LocalTime userTime = LocalTime.parse(start); 
                  LocalTime currentTime=LocalTime.now();
                  long hr=ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(currentTime,userTime);
                  System.out.println("Total number of hours: "+hr);

Comment: no you dont have to split anything, you only have to enter time with hh:mm format e.g : "10:30"